# css div positioning

Tags: css, html

What float and clear properties do I need to use in order to achieve the following layout?
They are not part of a list, simply divs that should float next to each other as shown below.

[image]

Comment: build an dive around div#1 and div#2. this one and #3 and #4 are floating left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that order, declare :

```
div4 float right
div3 float right
div1
div2
```

But the final layout will depend on the size of the divs, if their size does not match your schema, strange results might occur...

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left">
            <div style="background-color:Gray;width:100px;height:100px">
                div1
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:Yellow;width:100px;height:300px;">
            div4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;background-color:Green;width:100px;height:400px">
            div2
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;background-color:Maroon;width:100px;height:400px">
            div3
    </div>
</div>
```

Adjust width and padding according your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need two wrapper divs and some simple floats:

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
     <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
     <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
 </div> 
 <div id="right">
     <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
     <div id="div4">Div 4</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
div 
{
    width: 100px:;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
}

#left
{
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#right,
#right div
{
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

#right div
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Change widths to your taste :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/ED5Rf/

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `less markup` like this:

**Css:**

```
.first, .second{
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:Yellow;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
.second{
    height: 60px;
    background-color:Blue;
}
.third, .fourth{
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:Green;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:-100px;
 }
.fourth{
    background-color:Red;
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="first">1</div>
<div class="second">2</div>
<div class="third">3</div>
<div class="fourth">4</div>
```

Check the fiddle

### http://jsfiddle.net/h7qfL/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="dMain">
  <div id="d" class="flt">
     <div id="d1"></div>
     <div id="d2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="d2" class="flt">

  </div>
  <div id="d3" class="flt">

  </div>
<br class="cls" />
</div>
```

style:

```
.flt{ float:left; }
.cls{clear:both;}
```

This will do. Float is used to float things around. like float:left means, it will float on the left side of the text. clear is used to clear off any such floating. For more head out to w3school.

Answer (score 0):

You can put divs numbers 1 and 2 within div(#first) and also divs 3 and 4 in another div(#second). You then set div #first float to left and also the #div3 float left.

like that:

```
  <div id="first" style="float:left">
     <div id="div1"></div>
     <div id="div2"></div>
 </div> 
 <div id="second">
     <div id="div3" style="float:left"></div>
     <div id="div4"></div>
  </div>
```

You also need to write the width and height for every div.